# Are land borders between Thailand and Cambodia still closed? (April 2022)

Tags: borders, thailand, cambodia

I am looking to travel to Thailand but cross over to Cambodia once my tourist visa expires (30 days).

I am wondering if I will need to fly to Cambodia or if I can take a bus from Bangkok.

The [UK Gov website states](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/cambodia/entry-requirements#regional-travel) that the land borders are closed:

> The Cambodia-Laos, Cambodia-Thailand and Cambodia-Vietnam land borders are closed to travellers.
> Recent changes to visa requirements for Thailand may affect travellers wishing to make regular crossings at the land border between Cambodia and Thailand.

Is this still true? I don't know when this page was last updated.

Comment: Cambodia's land borders were closed from all its neighbours (as stated on the UK site). On [this page](https://www.mfaic.gov.kh/covid-19) Cambodia's Ministry of Tourism states the easing of Covid-19 restrictions *"for travelers arriving by air, **land** and sea from 17th March 2022. The removal of unnecessary barriers . . ."* But it does not explicitly say that closed land borders are now open, and I can't find any other mention on their official tourism pages. There is an email address at the bottom: admin@mot.gov.kh.

Comment: There is also a website mentioned https://www.tourismcambodia.org/ but the link "Getting to Cambodia" doesn't say much.

Comment: The Spanish embassy information says that since March 17th Cambodia is open to vaccinated travellers. It doesn't specify if it only applies to people arriving by air or also land. https://exteriores.gob.es/es/ServiciosAlCiudadano/Paginas/Detalle-recomendaciones-de-viaje.aspx?trc=Camboya